# how to I get value of excel using C#, if a cell has error

Tags: c#, excel

For e.g., a cell with =1-b would have #Name error, but if I use .Value, it would return -2146826259, if I use .Text, it would return #Name, how could I get =1-b? Thanks in prior.

Comment: Have you defined ”b” as a variable or name?

Comment: What library for C# integration are you using?

Comment: hi Ethan, can you confirm if the solution below answered your query, if yes, please mark it as answered by clicking the green tickbox next to answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `ExcelInterop` Reference you can do this to get Formula value

`var cellValue = (xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] as Range).Formula;`

**Main**

```
string pathToExcelFile = @"C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Book1.xlsx";

Application xlApp = new Application();
Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(pathToExcelFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

_Worksheet xlWorksheet = (_Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

var cellValue = (xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] as Range).Formula;
```

**Output**

*=1-b*